# What is type level annotation?

Tags: java, junit5

What is a type level annotation?

I was reading the doc of @TestInstance and there it is written that it is a type-level annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an official term - it doesn't appear in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/index.html). But we can still understand what it means by combining the meaning of the three words "type", "level" and "annotation".

A "type level annotation" is an annotation applied at the *type* level (in other words, on a type), rather than, say, at the method level.

```
@TestInstance(LifeCycle.PER_CLASS) // applied to the class
class MyTest {
    // @TestInstance(LifeCycle.PER_CLASS) // should not annotate a method with this
    @Test
    public void fooWorks() { ... }
}
```

This is also suggested by the `@Target` annotation present on [`TestInstance`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.html):

```
@Target(value=TYPE)
```

The parameter is [`ElementType.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE), which limits the annotation's target to the following things:

> Class, interface (including annotation interface), enum, or record declaration

These stack overflow posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359474/java-type-level-annotation-and-private-member-visibility), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050521/java-validation-type-level-annotation-for-multiple-types), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63587444/is-a-type-level-annotation-always-inherited-by-public-methods-of-that-type)) also use "type level annotation" in this way. I also found [this page](https://coderanch.com/t/649919/certification/Type-level-annotation-overriden-deployment) which uses the terms "method level" and "field level" annotations, which follows a similar logic.

Basically, you can think of "X-level annotation" as "this annotation marks an X", which in turn means "X is one of the things in the annotation's `@Target` meta-annotation".

---

Note that "type level annotation" should not be confused with "[type annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4)", a term that *does* appear in the JLS. A "type annotation" is one that can annotate the *use* of a type (corresponds to `ElementType.TYPE_USE`), as opposed to declarations.

Comment: The JLS does mention [declaration annotations and type annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.4), and what is meant by "type annotation" is something else than what you explain here. It's an annotation that modifies the meaning of a type, rather than an annotation that is applied to a user-defined type. Type annotations are rarely used in Java, and you need special tools like the [Checker Framework](https://checkerframework.org) to make them useful.

Comment: @Jesper yeah they are a very different thing, which was why I didn't include them in my answer. But now that you mention it, maybe I should include it as a little note at the end since the names are so similar.

Answer (score 2):

A "type-level annotation" is an annotation, which is applied to a type. The documentation of [`ElementType.TYPE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE) defines it as follow:

> `public static final ElementType TYPE`
>
> Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration

So you write this `@TestInstance` annotation most likely for your test suite class.